# Code for implementation of Kruskal's algo produces wrong o/p

Tags: java, graph, heap, kruskals-algorithm, union-find

Below is the program to find cost of minimum spanning tree, the graph is represented as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. So first I stored all the edges in a `minHeap` and polled them by checking if they form a cycle or not. If not, I included the `weight` of that edge in the result. My code gives wrong o/p for some testcases.

for eg.-

```
Input:

42(vertices) 458(edges)

1(u) 2(v) 214(weight)
1 8 486 
1 9 584 
1 12 178 
1 14 91 
1 15 146 
1 17 125 
1 20 570 
1 21 953 
1 24 589 
1 30 276 
1 31 634 
1 33 135 
1 34 811 
1 36 309...
```

```
Its Correct output is:
2361
```

```
And Your Code's output is:
2164
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
class MST {
    static int spanningTree(int V, int E, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph) {
        // Add your code here
        PriorityQueue<edge>heap=new PriorityQueue<>((e1,e2)->e1.wt-e2.wt);
        
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<V;j++){
                if(graph.get(i).get(j)>0){
                    heap.offer(new edge(i,j,graph.get(i).get(j)));
                    graph.get(j).set(i,0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        int [] parent=new int[V];
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
            parent[i]=i;
            
        int res=0;
        int edges=0;
        while(edges<V-1){
            edge e=heap.poll();
            if(!formCycle(parent,e.sc,e.dt)){
                res+=e.wt;
                edges++;
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
    
    static boolean formCycle(int [] parent,int sc,int dt){
        if(parent[sc]==parent[dt])
            return true;
            
        int p1=findParent(parent,sc);
        int p2=findParent(parent,dt);
        
        parent[p2]=p1;
        
        return false;
    }
    
    static int findParent(int [] parent,int i){
        if(parent[i]==i)
            return i;
            
        return parent[i]=findParent(parent,parent[i]);
    }
}

class edge{
    int sc,dt,wt;
    edge(int sc,int dt,int wt){
        this.sc=sc;
        this.dt=dt;
        this.wt=wt;
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick observation is, your code is expecting 0-based vertex-ids (i.e., vertex-id will be 0 to V-1), but your input indicates the vertex-ids might be 1-based (i.e., vertex-id will be 1 to V). I am just making assumption based on what you provide. Please double check that.

Comment: Also, while asking, please attach `Minimal Reproducible Code` and appropriate input-set which produces the wrong answer.